# Delete parameters in SqlDatasource in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource

I have a `Gridview` which is connected with `SqlDataSource` for Data.
I have `Edit` and `Delete` built in functionality. I have passed the `Stored Procedure` for the `SelectCommand`.

Now I want to delete record and simultaneously update another table, now I do not get how to pass the values for the delete parameters in `DeleteCommand`

I also added `DataKeyNames` wherein I have provided the field (which is `Primary Key and Auto Increment`), but that too does not works.
While deleting it simply says, `Deleting is Supported, because no DeleteCommand is Specified`.

I also tried creating a `StoredProcedure` for the delete task, but my StoredProcedure need to have some parameters so that I can update the records in another table.

Can anyone tell how could I pass the value for the Delete parameter.

**UPDATED with SqlDataSource Markup**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="StudAllotmentDataSource" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SiteSqlServer %>" 
    SelectCommand="user_GetStudAllotment" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="user_DeleteAllottedStudBook" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">
   <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="BookCode" Type="String" /> 
        <asp:Parameter Name="Quantity" Type="String" /> 
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you specify DeleteCommand as your stored procedure in the sqlserverdatasource?

Comment: yes i have, but that requires 2 parameters, which i need, to utilize for updating records in another table

Comment: you are using the same datakeynames in your stored procedure, right?
I mean something like ... where BookCode = '@BookCode' and Quantity = '@Quantity' and quantity is your data key?

Comment: I had to put single quotes on the parameters like this '@Quantity' because I could not make comment with this directly @Quantity, so understand my code accordingly

Comment: Let me clear the whole concept, i have 2 tables "StudentLibrary (BookCode (Primary), Quantity)" and "StudentAllotment (StudAllotmentID (Primary and Identity), BookCode, Quantity)", now when the allotment is deleted i want to udpate the studentlibrary with the quantity of books deleted from allotment, so the gridviews datakey is StudAllotmentID, as i am showing allotments in the GridView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21937/discussion-between-abbas-and-pawan-nogariya)